# how do I write a select statement that will evaluate multiple fields to populate a new field value?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2016

I’ve been rummaging through a bunch of postings, but haven’t found one that fits my issue. I’ve tried CASE and IIF, but none seem to work. My wife would say I don’t know how to Google correctly. I have an export loaded into both SQL Server Express 15 and Access 16 (365). I can use either to accomplish my goals. I have a table imported from a data export with these fields:

```
LogonID
DeptName
CertDate
CertStatus
PastDue
```

I need to write a query that will provide a Status field with the appropriate value where:

```sql
If ((CertDate Is Not Null) AND (CertStatus = ‘Current’) AND (PastDue = ‘No’)) then
    Status = ‘ReadOnTime’)

If ((CertDate Is Not Null) AND (CertStatus = ‘Current’) AND (PastDue = ‘Yes’)) then
    Status = ‘ReadLate’)

If ((CertDate Is Null) AND (CertStatus = ‘Pending’) AND (PastDue = ‘Yes’)) then
    Status = ‘UnReadLate’)
```

Anything else is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you would use the [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression.

I used the field names from your sample and you did not provide a table name so you will have to update the example to fit your needs.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [CertDate] IS NOT NULL
                 AND [CertStatus] = 'Current'
                 AND [PassDue] = 'No' THEN 'ReadOnTime'
            WHEN [CertDate] IS NOT NULL
                 AND [CertStatus] = 'Current'
                 AND [PassDue] = 'Yes' THEN 'ReadLate'
            WHEN [CertDate] IS NULL
                 AND [CertStatus] = 'Pending'
                 AND [PassDue] = 'Yes' THEN 'UnReadLate'
            ELSE ''
       END AS [Status]
FROM   [YourTableName];
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't select both. SQL and Access SQL code works wonderfully. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the query looks like in Access SQL.

```
Select
    LogonID, 
    DeptName, 
    CertDate, 
    CertStatus, 
    PastDue, 
    IIf (CertDate Is Not Null AND CertStatus = "Current" AND PastDue = "No", "ReadOnTime",
    IIf (CertDate Is Not Null AND CertStatus = "Current" AND PastDue = "Yes", "ReadLate",
    IIf (CertDate Is Null AND CertStatus = "Pending" AND PastDue = "Yes", "UnReadLate",
     ""))) As Status 
From        Table
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't select both. SQL and Access SQL code works wonderfully. Thank you both.

Answer (score -1):

What syntaxes did you try?
I would go whith something like

```
update table my_table set
Status = (case when condition1 then 'ReadOnTime' 
else when condition2 then 'ReadLate' 
else when condition2 then 'UnReadLate' 
else '' end)
```